# Design MongoDB document to get desired Neo4j graph

Tags: mongodb, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am new to stack overflow and database systems - looking to build a simple recommendation system using polyglot persistence in Neo4j and MongoDB. I am using *mongo-connector* and *neo4j doc manager* to actively push data from MongoDB to Neo4j. I am unable to control how the MongoDB data is being pushed to the neo4j and not being able to have this graph structure in Neo4j:

[image: Neo4j Graph].

- What should be the appropriate document and collection in the MongoDB? OR
- How to design a simple course recommendation system using MongoDB and Neo4j?

Thank you!

Comment: The graph model in your picture above looks ok. But what's the purpose of MongoDB in your use case?

Comment: I am trying to explore polyglot persistence such that I would fetch the data from a JSON file, store it into the MongoDB. Push the MongoDB collections to Neo4j and use Cypher for query the Neo4j graph and find recommendations. More of learning how it works.

Thank you!

Comment: Makes sense as an exercise. You could also load the JSON directly into Neo4j: No second database and synchronisation needed, and a redundancy-free persistence. See also https://neo4j.com/blog/cypher-load-json-from-url/